# remove var from global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

In this example I have two action :

1. when you add quantity of users - it will be automatically calculated by a price in the input with total sum
2. when you already add the quantity of users > total sum is calculated > if you click on EUR - in input with total sum, the sum will be translated to euro.

So, every thing work fine - but I don't like that the "usesQuantity" has the global scope!
Any ideas how make it local and save the working version
http://jsfiddle.net/gb2447jd/5/

tried something like:

```
$('#user-quantity').keyup(function(){
    var userQuantity = parseInt($(this).val());
    if( userQuantity >=1 && userQuantity <=200){
      valid(userQuantity);
    } else {
      $('#total-sum').val("error");
    }
  });


  $('#usd').on('click', function(){
    $('#eur').removeClass('greenChacked');
    $(this).addClass('greenChacked');
    valid(userQuantity);
  });
  $('#eur').on('click', function(){
    $('#usd').removeClass('greenChacked');
    $(this).addClass('greenChacked');
    valid(userQuantity);
  });
  $('#usd').trigger('click');

  function valid(userQuantity){
    if( $('#usd').hasClass('greenChacked') ){
      var usdCurr = userQuantity * 10 + 'doll';
      $('#total-sum').val(usdCurr);
    }
    if( $('#eur').hasClass('greenChacked') ){
      var eurCurr = userQuantity * 5 + 'eur';
      $('#total-sum').val(eurCurr);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your code inside a [immediately invoked function](http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
(function () {
    var userQuantity;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //rest of your code 
    };
}());
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307078/jquery-best-practises-in-case-of-document-ready).

Answer (score 1):

Define your variable (userQuantity) within the function.  It will be available via closure to the other functions and callbacks without having global scope.  See this new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/gb2447jd/6/).

The start of the new code looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userQuantity;
    $('#user-quantity').keyup(function () {
        userQuantity = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (userQuantity >= 1 && userQuantity <= 200) {
            setCurrency();
        } else {
            $('#total-sum').val("error");
        }
    });
```